# selectedFeatureCount vs featureCount?

Tags: qgis, python

I do

```
from qgis.core import *
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\file.shp", "boundingBoxes", "ogr")
layer.featureCount()
```

outcome  is 428

```
layer.select(layer.pendingAllAttributesList())
layer.selectedFeatureCount()
```

outcome is 0

Why the results are not equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **`layer.featureCount()`** - Total Number of features in the layer.
- **`layer.selectedFeatureCount()`** - Total number of features that are actually selected on the map canvas for the particular layer
- **`layer.select(layer.pendingAllAttributesList())`** - This does not in fact make any visible map selection. What this does is to create an iterator to loop over all the features in the layer.

For making a real selection in the map, you will need to iterate and store the feature ids to a list and then pass it to [`setSelectedFeatures(const QgsFeatureIds & ids)`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a4d82285142c108ba73622ce53207759c) method. Like below..

```
layer.select(layer.pendingAllAttributesList())
ids = []
for feature in layer:
    ids.append(feature.id())
layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
```